# Считать данные из консоли python

Tags: python

Как сохранить данные из консоли python в переменную url0? Скрипт предполагается запускать на Windows 10.
Вариант ниже для Windows не подходит, как понимаю.
В идеале хочется, чтобы работало и на Windows, и на UNIX-подобных

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser
parser.add_argument('--url', action='store', dest='url0')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы назначали переменной `parser` значение самого метода, т.е. не вызвали его как функцию - необходимо добавить скобки: `argparse.ArgumentParser()` или там `argparse.ArgumentParser(description='my test')`. После этого работает как предполагается.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-u', '--url', action='store', dest='url0')
t1 = parser.parse_args(['--u', 'qwerty1'])
t2 = parser.parse_args(['--url', 'qwerty2'])
print t1.url0
print t2.url0
# qwerty1
# qwerty2
```

Comment: Дважды наступил на одни грабли, но сделал. Спасибо!